# How to download multiple sheets as csv files within a folder using google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, data-analysis, tableau-desktop

I'm trying to download this dataset that includes multiple sheets using Google Sheets. Is there a way to download every single sheet as a csv file into a single folder?

I tried to CTRL + click all sheets, select file, then select download as csv. The only thing that was downloaded was the current sheet I was on. I then tried to download the data as a pdf in a single file, which worked, but serves useless because I can't use it for analysis in Tableau. I need the files to be either csv or xlsx.

Answer (score 1):

When you save as csv, it only saves the current sheet as csv does not have multiple sheets.

So you have to save each sheet separately.